# Windows Clustering 2008 R2

Tags: high-availability, failover, windows-server

I'm trying to build a Windows cluster with 3 nodes, 2 Active and 1 Passive, And If I have to build in  a way like N1 Active - N3 Passive will be refer as "cluster network 1" and N2 Active and N3 Passive refer as "Cluster Network 2"..

So here my question is, can I have Node 3 tied to two different cluster networks?? I'm sorry if this a dumb question... But any suggestions would really help me..

Comment: Are you talking about clustering SQL? If not you should post this question on another site.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about SQL Clustering on top of windows server failover clustering...

Comment: OK. How many instances are you installing on the cluster?

Comment: 1 instance on node 1 and node 2 and node 3 will be added as passive to node 1 and also node 2... So, node 3 will have 2 instances..

Comment: I think all you need to do is set preferred owners for the resource groups. I could be misunderstanding what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you Jon... I did set up the preferred owners for resource group... But my question is can I have Node 3 tied to 2 different cluster networks.. I'm sorry if my question going out of the box of SQL clustering...

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like a bad idea as far as complexity goes. I'm missing why doing so is necessary, though.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is I was given with 3 servers and asked to build 2 different cluster Active/Passive... And the 3rd Node should be able to host 2 Active Nodes N1, N2 in worst case scenarios... I'm sorry if I'm not able to interpret my case... in words and confusing others... Anyways thank you for your time in responding..

Comment: Again, unless I'm missing something, a single 3-node cluster with 2 instances of SQL Server running on it will meet the requirements.